# How to get records from list view

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I used listview control to add records in it, and wanted to get all records and pass it to my function.

how could i retrieve subitems values as i have 15 column, 15 rows, bit confuse.

actually i did insertion part but don't have idea regarding how to get records for list view

private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        listView1.Items.Add(cmb_company_id.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(cmb_po_no.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(cmb_size.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txt_quantity.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(cmb_design_no.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(cmb_quality.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txt_aria.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(receive_date.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(delevry_date.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(txt_remark.Text);
        listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Tag = listView1.Items.Count - 1;
    }
```

Comment: actually i did insertion part but don't have idea regarding how to get records for listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Count; i++)
    {
       string s = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[i].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Items and SubItems properties of ListView, though this is not tested:

```
string str = string.Empty;
for(int i=0; i<lstView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<lstView.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
    {
        str = lstView.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: If number of columns are fixed then write `for(int j=0; j<15; j++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach(Selected Row in YourListView)  
{  
  //Create instance of a ListViewRow and assign the selected listviewrow in it  
  ListViewRow newRow = Row;

  //Then get th esub item value  
  variable = value;  
}
```

this is just a hint.